# MongoDb's change stream in NestJs

Tags: mongodb, stream, nestjs

I look around on how mongoDb change stream can be implemented in NestJs but so far, i can't find any solution or documentation.

There is a similar way by using Hooks middleware, but this can't be triggered if we change data from external app.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Cat.name,
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
          const schema = CatsSchema;
          schema.post('save', function() {
            console.log(
              `${configService.get('APP_NAME')}: Hello from post save`,
            ),
          });
          return schema;
        },
        inject: [ConfigService],
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I found this document https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/ but how can we implement this in NestJs?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work. I wasn't able to test this since I don't have a replica set set up.

```
@Injectable()
export class ChangeStreamService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Schema.name) private schemaModel: Model<SchemaDocument>) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.schemaModel.collection.watch<SchemaDocument>().on('change', (e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to try this but I have to configure a replica set first. Never done that before - will see how it goes.